# how to make iterative process for plate and cover temperature of a solar air heater?

Tags: matlab

I wrote a MATLAB code for a flat plate solar heater and I'm facing a problem with iteration process. I need to make iteration for both plate and gass cover temperature so I can compelete the code finding other related quantities. At first I estimated both plate and gass cover temperature and after that I calculated the heat transfer coefficients based on these estimation, but I need to get the right values for these two temperatures.

I try MATLAB code for this

Comment: Please post a [mre] including your code, any error messages your getting along with your current results, and your expected results.